# Error when giving a vector of vectors it's dimensions

Tags: c++, eclipse, vector

```
class tablero
{
int filas_; //initialize both ints
int columnas_;
vector < vector < casilla > > casilla_; // a vector of vectors of Casillas
public:
tablero(int filas, int columnas)
// The above is an initialization list
// We initialize casilla_ as a vector of filas vectors of columnas Casillas
{

  filas_=filas; //put the rows in the row int
 columnas_=columnas; // and the columns in the columns
 casilla_ = filas , vector<casilla>(columnas); // and set the dimensions of the vector of vectors.

}
```

It gives me the" no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector >’ and ‘int’) "Error in the casilla_ = filas, vector(columnas).filas(rows) columnas(columns).

I think it's everything fine, but I don't really know why this error shows up. In the Tablero.h my constructor is:

```
class Tablero {
public:
Tablero(int filas,int columnas); //I added both ints because I had an error in the main.
virtual ~Tablero();
void setcol(int n); //other methods
void setfilas(int n);
vector<vector<casilla> > getCasilla();
void setCasillac(int n ,int t, casilla c);
casilla getCasillac(int n ,int t);
};
```

If you need the class casilla and other stuff just say it and I'll post it.
I'm new in c++ and eclipse, I'm used to Netbeans and java, and I don't know how to handle these excepcions.

Thanks to anyone who can help me, and of course, if you need some more code, say it and I'll edit this post and put it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you can't assign an int to a vector :

use : 
cassilla_.reserve(filas) ;
vector(columnas) ;

Or use pointers to these and pass in the value at construction time.

Comment: It works for stopping the error, but in Casilla.h shows now an error:undefined reference to `vtable for std::casilla'.

And in every method that I use Tablero to get to a Casilla ( like t.getCasillac(int fila int columna) shows an error that was not there.

Comment: That is because there is no such thing in the std namespace as a casilla. Can I assume that you are building a class that will represent a grid of data? i.e. A database table. If this is the case then you only need to store the columns value once as an int as the width of the table should be constant. If you want to you can post casilla.h and .cpp and maybe a better description of what you are trying to achieve.